# Rails & JQuery how to show the newly inserted data from after create without refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have here two partials in the index view which is the _table which have all the suppliers & _popup got the form inside , after submitting this form it should hide the modal and update the table with the last inserted supplier to the database without refreshing , i have seen a lot of  tutorials doing that but not for a table  or for a partial 
here is the code i tried to do with .

here is my controller:

```
def index
  @suppliers  = Supplier.all
  @supplier   = Supplier.new
end

def create
  @supplier = Supplier.new(supplier_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @supplier.save
      format.html { redirect_to @supplier, notice:  (t '.notice') }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @supplier }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: @supplier.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```html
<%- model_class = Supplier -%>
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
  <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
            <div class="portlet light bordered">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption font-dark">
                        <i class="icon-settings font-dark"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase"><%= t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tools"> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="suppliers">
                    <%= render 'table' %>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <%= link_to  t('helpers.links.new_supplier') , '#splash', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' , 'class' => 'btn btn-success mb-10' %>                                    

<%= render 'form' %>

  </div>
```

i created a create.js.erb file so that it run after submitting the form

```
// hide the popup
$('#splash').modal('hide');
// reset the form inputs
$("#new_supplier")[0].reset();
```

everything working fine till now , but how to reload the partial table so that it contain what is just submitted without refreshing the page 
i tried watching a lot of tutorials but didn't contain what i'm looking for 
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your create.is.erb file:

```
$("#suppliers").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'table' ) %>");
```

This way you re-render the table partial through JavaScript without refreshing the page.

Comment: it worked :) but all table's styling gone ... why is that !!

Comment: If you use Google Chrome you can use inspect element and check for console errors. Or check your terminal for possible errors. Maybe the div with the suppliers_id is also replaced, thereby causing a loss in styling.

Comment: already checked that but everything seems right !! maybe the plugins need to be reloaded for the div ? but i dont know how to do that

Comment: The html has the correct suppliers div? Is there no styling at all or just not for the table? Just in case, restart your server too.

Comment: yes the table container still " suppliers " and the table id still "sample_1"
the layout working fine only the table got no style

Comment: I have never had this problem, are you doing something fancy (not regular css) for the table styling? It is also possible to pass a layout option when rendering a partial, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: yes the table is customized from a theme that i bought it got custom styling and js ..

Comment: I see, that is where the problem lies. My answer did answer you original question though, can you accept/upvote it?